# Failed to load response due to okhttp3.internal.http -RealResponseBody@d35e75 - Error on Android Studio after implemented ChatGpt

Tags: java, android, chatbot, openai-api

Below is my code and I don't understand what could be the problem here. Please help me as I am unable to implement it any other way. Any help would be appreciated with this regard. I am basically trying to implement the API with the okhttp library.

```
        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonBody.put("model","gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct");
            jsonBody.put("prompt",question);
            jsonBody.put("max_tokens",1000);
            jsonBody.put("temperature",0);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(jsonBody.toString(),JSON);
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://api.openai.com/v1/completions")
                .header("Authorization","Bearer MY-KEY")
                .post(body)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                addResponse("Failed to load response due to "+e.getMessage());
            }
    }
```

Comment: You did not yell what your code should do. Nor did you tell if you got errors and if which ones.

Comment: There are no errors but when i run the app and basically i want to make it like a chatgpt app. on asking any question or prompting in anyway it just gives me the above stated response i.e. Failed to load response due to okhttp3.internal.http -RealResponseBody@d35e75
I want it to work like chatgpt

Comment: My hint was ment to let you write a normal post. Not to put important info afterwards in a comment. This 'this' makes no sense.